# How to change value in prepared statement for each value

Tags: java, jdbc, sql-insert

I am executing the below code in order to execute insert in batches.

```
String idlist=1,2,3;
PreparedStatement stmt = conn
        .prepareStatement("INSERT INTO TEST.SAMPLE VALUES"
                + " (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?,ARRAY("+ idlist +"))";
for (int i = 1; i <= ITERATION_MAX; i++) {

    idlist=listofdata.get(i).get_idlist();
    stmt.setInt(1, listofdata.get(i).get_id());
    stmt.setInt(2, listofdata.get(i).get_name());
    stmt.setInt(3, listofdata.get(i).get_place());
    stmt.setInt(4, listofdata.get(i).get_year());
    stmt.setInt(5, listofdata.get(i).get_day());
    stmt.setInt(6, listofdata.get(i).get_rollno());
    stmt.setInt(7, listofdata.get(i).get_main_subject());
    stmt.setArray(8, listofdata.get(i).get_elective());

    stmt.addBatch();
}

   stmt.executeBatch();
```

But here there is an String called idlist (which cannot be set) which is concatenated with the insert statement each time.

But the value of idlist is updated in each loop by `listofdata.get(i).get_idlist();`

I cannot set as the parameter because there is a data type conflict issue(HANA database).So I have to do by this only .But how to keep the idlist value change for each statement. It does not changes for the whole batch.Any help is appreciated

Comment: I hope SCHEMA.TABLE is deliberate obfuscation on your part and not the names you're using.  Someone needs to tell you that this is a denormalized schema.  Your list could be better normalized as a 1:many parent-child foreign key relationship.

Comment: I don't thing the problem is with parent-child foriegn key relationship.The problem is how to update the value of idlist in each prepared statements

Comment: I don't think you understand what normalization is.

Comment: @duffymo There are many cases when denormalized tables are needed and used (as example Fact tables in OLAP star schemas)

Comment: Yes, but I doubt that this is one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not know how many ids will be in `idlist` there is no way to use same prepared statement, because number of parameters changes (i.e. number of `?`)

Prepared statement can be used only with exact same SQL string.

But it seems like you have to have always same number of parameters because they are columns in the table.

Then build SQL string with corresponding number of `?`. Or if they are nullable (I guess so) make it with `?` for all columns.

Then when you set parameters you need to loop through your idlist, set available and for the rest set parameters as null.